# Why the JobService did not repeat?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I am trying to developing `JobScheduler`, and I want the App to do something every 1 minute when App has been killed by system.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
    android:name=".BaiduPush.BaiduJobService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main2)


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            startJobService()
        }
}

private fun startJobService() {
        Log.d(TAG,"startBaiduJobService")
        val JOB = 10
        val jobScheler = getSystemService((Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE)) as JobScheduler
        val jobinfo = JobInfo.Builder(JOB, ComponentName(packageName,BaiduJobService::class.java.name))
                //.setPeriodic(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES)
                .setOverrideDeadline(60000)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()

        jobScheler.schedule(jobinfo)
    }
```

**BaiduJobService**

```
class BaiduJobService : JobService() {

    val TAG = "BaiduJobService"

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG,"BaiduJobService onStartJob")
        return true
    }
    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

}
```

When I use the `setPeriodic(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES)`. The `onStartJob` has not been called.

When I use the `setOverrideDeadline(60000)`. The `onStartJob` only show once times at the first.

But the `BaiduJobService` seems not called when time is up.

Did I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maintain minimum gap.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya can you explain more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I am Using Alarm Manager For Keep my service alive it is better than a job scheduler. I implement this code in service oncreate() method.

```
public class CallService extends Service {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RestartServiceBroadcast.class);
            mKeepAlivePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            ((AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, 60000, mKeepAlivePendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

Create BroadcastReceiver to call service again in onRecieve

```
public class RestartServiceBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("service.RestartService")) {
        // Here Call a Service
    }

    }
}
```

Manifest Like this

```
 <receiver
                android:name=".service.receiver.RestartServiceBroadcast"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sipStack">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="service.RestartService" />
                </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".service.CallService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false">

        </service>
```

Comment: Does the `AlarmManager` will launch when the App has been killed by Android system ?

Comment: Yes, I am tested in android oreo version and its working fine for me

Comment: I have try, but it seems not alarm when the App has killed from background. Can you post your code?

Comment: yaa sure.. Happy Coding

Comment: Is your debug android device version Android Oreo ?

Comment: Yes, I am testing in oreo with all OS like oxygen, color os, and miui os, I am developing a VoIP Application and in my application one sip service is continuing running after an app is destroying or killed. and one more thing you are set your app is always running background and battery optimization.